# Analytic of a line

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given points $A(-4,-4), B (-8,-2)$ and $C(x,0)$, what is $x$

1. If $AC-CB$ has its greatest value
2. If $AC+CB$ has its smallest value

I know that if $A$ and $B$ and $C$ are collinear $AC-BC$ has its greatest value so $x$ is $-12$ and $AC+BC$  also has its smallest value when they points $A,B,C$ are collinear so $x$ must be $-12$ again but answer is $-20/3$ why is this so 
I think this question might be solved using calculus which I haven't studied yet is there any way I can solve this without calculus?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$AC-BC$$ is given by $$\sqrt{(x+4)^2+16}-\sqrt{(x+8)^2+4}$$
and $$AC+BC=\sqrt{(x+4)^2+16}+\sqrt{(x+8)^2+4}$$
and $$AC-BC\le 2\sqrt{5}$$ for $x=-12$
and $$AC+BC\geq 2\sqrt{13}$$ for $$x=-\frac{20}{3}$$

Comment: Where did $2sqrt(5)$ come from? Or 2sqrt(13)

Comment: i have computed the extrema